Why do we define Lie algebra cohomology on anti-symmetric maps but no such condition on group cohomology?
The Lie algebra cohomology is defined as follows: For $A$ a $\mathfrak{g}$ module. Let $C_k=\operatorname{Hom}(\bigwedge ^{k}\mathfrak{g},A)$. One can define operator $d_k: C_k\to C_{k+1}$, and cohomology is defined as $\operatorname{ker}(d_k)/\operatorname{Im}(d_{k-1})$. And group cohomology is defined in similar way, despite that $C_k=\operatorname{Hom}(G^k,A)$. So why are they different?

Because they are different algebraic objects?

A group is not a Lie algebra, however you could try to search for links between group cohomology of a Lie group and the cohomology of its associated Lie algebra

There is actually another way of computing the same Lie algebra cohomology, with the complex being $C^k = \mathrm{Hom}(U\mathfrak g\otimes\dots\otimes U\mathfrak g, A)$; it resembles the complex from the group case much more.
It is a typical feature of cohomologies that they can be computed via several complexes. In our case, both the Lie algebra cohomology and the group cohomology are the derived functors of the ($\mathfrak g$- or $G$-) invariants. What it means is that we should find a free (or at least projective) resolution $D_k$ of the trivial ($\mathfrak g$- or $G$-)representation and then compute the cohomology of the complex $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak g\text{-mod}}(D_\bullet, A)$.
One such a resolution has $D_k=\bigwedge^k\mathfrak g\otimes U\mathfrak g$, giving the complex you mention, another resolution ("bar") has $D_k=U\mathfrak g\otimes\dots\otimes U\mathfrak g$ ($k+1$-times). For a (general) group the 1st resolution has no analogy, but the 2nd one does and gives the standard way of computing group cohomology. In special cases you can find other useful free resolutions.

Exactly! :) To "define" (co-) homology in terms of one special complex is not a good idea, though there are many precedents for it. :)  I can't help but remark that it was a great relief to me, many years ago by now, to learn about the idea of "derived functors" of half-exact functions, many of which are very tangible (fixed-vectors, cofixed, etc.) :)
